# Getting a page content with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, httprequest, html, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to get the content of a HTTP request into a QString variable with Qt and C++

```
QNetworkAccessManager networkManager;

QUrl url("https://someurl.test.com/this-actually-exists");
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(url);

QNetworkReply* currentReply = networkManager.get(request);  // GET

QString reply = QTextCodec::codecForMib(1015)->toUnicode(currentReply->readAll());
```

Still, the variable `reply` seems to stay empty. Obviously, I misunderstand the documentation. How do I get this to perform?

Comment: You have to connect to the QNetworkReply's signals to be notified when the content is available before you can read from it.

Comment: So I need to create a slot, have a callback function, and hope that one executes, much like an AJAX request in JavaScript?

Comment: Yup, there's examples of how to do this right there in the Qt docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two different ways even the synchronous or asynchronous ways to do this. The asynchronous way is :

```
connect (&networkManager , SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)) ,this, SLOT(done(QNetworkReply*)));

networkManager.get(request);
```

And you should read the contents from the returned reply in the slot connected to `finished` signal in the following way :

```
void net::done(QNetworkReply * reply) 
{
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
       data = QString(reply->readAll ());
    }
    else
    {
       data = QString(reply->errorString ());
    }
}
```

The synchronous way is like :

```
   QNetworkReply *reply = networkManager.get(request);

   QEventLoop loop;
   connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
   connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
   loop.exec();

   QByteArray bts = reply->readAll();
   QString str(bts);
```

Here you use an event loop to wait until the reply is finished and then read the available bytes and get the string.

Answer (score 1):

I need to assume you're running an application with an event-loop in place?  If not, then it's a bit harder...

If so, replace your last line that builds the reply QString:

```
connect(currentReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(gotAReply()));
```

Then you'll have to define another method in your class as a slot that gets triggered as soon as that reply got filled:

```
void gotAReply()
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(QObject::sender());

    if (reply)
    {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
        {
            QString replyText( reply->readAll() );
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
    }
}
```

Don't forget: for Signals and Slot to work your class declaration must contain the Q_OBJECT macro.

Comment: error: 'sender' was not declared in this scope
     QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
                                                                ^

Comment: fixed it, sry. static QObject* QObject::sender() is meant.  Have a look at signals and slots for that.